# Did Hitler receive congratulation telegrams from all corners of the Arab world for the introduction of Nuremberg racial laws in 1935?

Tags: nazi-germany

Mitchell G. Bard states that Hitler received congratulation telegrams from all corners of the Arab world when he introduced the Nuremberg racial laws in 1935. Is this true apart from the source provided as "A History of Israel: From the Rise of Zionism to Our Time page 196 by Howard Sachar"?

> When Hitler introduced the Nuremberg racial laws in 1935, he received telegrams of congratulation from all corners of the Arab world. [Source: Chapter 11: Treatment of Jews in the Arab World](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/myths-and-facts-treatment-of-jews-in-the-arab-world-chapter-11)

Comment: I can't answer this definitely, but I don't understand what "all corners of the Arab world" means.  The Sachar book exists, but I'm not given a whole lot of confidence that the citation on that website is a link that leads you to a book about the movie "It's a Wonderful Life": https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=067944632X/theamericanisraeA/.

Comment: I could see the same quote here in the book but not its original source-https://books.google.co.in/books?id=7qS0aRI5omwC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Nuremberg+racial+laws.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes.**
The wikipedia page of [Antisemitism in the Arab world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisemitism_in_the_Arab_world) quotes Bernard Lewis's book *Semites and Anti-Semites: An Inquiry into Conflict and Prejudice* as saying:

> After the promulgation of the Nuremberg Laws, Hitler received telegrams of congratulation from all over the Arab and Muslim world, especially from Morocco and Palestine, where the Nazi propaganda had been most active.... Before long political parties of the Nazi and Fascist type began to appear, complete with paramilitary youth organizations, colored shirts, strict discipline and more or less charismatic leaders.

Comment: This is a poor answer. Following the Lewis book, I find no citation for the claim.  Second, Lewis's book has been reviewed negatively for its lack of objectivity.  See this LA Times review, where the reviewer notes that Lewis is "using scholarly references to buttress partisan assertions."    http://articles.latimes.com/1986-10-26/books/bk-7499_1_bernard-lewis  If that many telegrams existed, I would think there should be much more solid historical evidence.  As it is, the evidence offered for the answer is a possibly biased book that does not cite a source for its claim.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Just search for 'telegrams' and you find it on page 148

Comment: @JanDoggen-You have beaten me to that-https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=ZTsiAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=An+Inquiry+Into+Conflict+and+Prejudice+arab&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHpdHzkMLSAhWBgLwKHfkqCb0Q6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=telegrams&f=false.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin-Wouldnt find that quote in the wrong page, its in page 148 as Jan Doggen mentioned and in the link I have given!

Comment: @pericles316 It's not that the quote doesn't appear but that the quote doesn't have a source.  Lewis's book is stating a fact without offering evidence.

Comment: @Roughon-Agree, a better answer should find the original source!

Comment: The wording of the quoted passage seems odd to me.  It almost sounds like he received telegrams from Palestine and Morocco, and that's being depicted as from "all over the Arab and Muslim world."  How do you "especially" receive a congratulatory telegram?  Seems like a binary proposition.  Interesting that no other nations are named, nor is a number given to give the scope of the wave of incoming telegrams.  Just my impression.